# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value (Help me Out Please)

Tags: c#, sql

This my code which i given below can please help me out why it show this type of error " SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= "

```
create procedure [dbo].[ManageClientContacts]

( 

  @ClientId int,
  @FirstName nvarchar(255)=null,
  @LastName nvarchar(255)=null,
  @City nvarchar(255)=null,
  @State nvarchar(255)=null,
  @Country nvarchar(255)=null,
  @PostalCode nvarchar(255)=null,
  @ContactName nvarchar(255)=null,
  @ContactNumber nvarchar(255)=null,
  @Email nvarchar(255)=null,
  @ContactEmail nvarchar(255)=null


  )

  as 
  begin

     If((select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails])<>@ClientId or (select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails]) is null )
          begin
             Insert into [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] 
                (
                ClientId ,FirstName ,LastName,City ,State ,Country ,PostalCode ,ContactName ,ContactNumber ,Email,ContactEmail,InsertedDate)
                values (
                @ClientId ,@FirstName ,@LastName,@City ,@State ,@Country ,@PostalCode ,@ContactName ,@ContactNumber ,@Email,@ContactEmail,getdate())


          end

        else

          begin

                Update  [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] set
              ClientId=@ClientId
              ,FirstName=@FirstName
              ,LastName=@LastName
              ,City=@City 
              ,[State]=@State 
              ,Country=@Country 
              ,PostalCode=@PostalCode 
              ,ContactName=@ContactName 
              ,ContactNumber=@ContactNumber 
              ,Email=@Email
              ,ContactEmail=@ContactEmail
              ,UpdatedDate=getdate()
                where ClientId=@ClientId


          end


  end


    RETURN 0
```

Comment: Specify code ya query

Comment: If you want someone to help you'll need to add your code and search query to your question

Comment: Why this is tagged as C#? It should be Sql Server or SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, your sub-query is returning more than one record where it is expected to return single value.

Look at your query

```
select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails]
```

This will return all the `clientId` stored in your table, which probably you don't want, so change your query like this

```
select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] where ClientId = @ClientId
```

so your `if` condition would be

```
If((select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] where ClientId = @ClientId)<>@ClientId or (select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] where ClientId = @ClientId) is null )
```

Comment: where i have to use this query this ??

Comment: in your `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

Your query

```
select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails])<>@ClientId
```

is causing the issue here. because `@ClientId` can hold one query while `select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails])` is returning more than one record so Sql server engine is confused with which value of result set I should be comparing the value of `@ClientId` and eventually resulted in error.

modify your query so that it just return only one record and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have used returned more than one value.
May be in your query you expected only one value. but it returned more than one value.
In your case i think there are more than one record with same client id or the query is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in this line :

```
If((select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails])<>@ClientId or (select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails]) is null )
```

**This condition expects one single return value** and in your case, it is returning more than one values and hence this cannot be processed by SQL Server.

Change your query in a way that it returns a single value based on the conditions in your query and you will be done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its simple. The query in your `if` condition should return only one value. In your case it returns more than one value and hence the error. You can try running that query alone and check. You will receive multiple results for that. You have to make sure that you return only one.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
If((select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails])<>@ClientId or (select ClientId from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails]) is null )
```

To this

```
If not exists
(
    select * from [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] where ClientId = @ClientId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your query as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ManageClientContacts]
( 
  @ClientId int,
  @FirstName nvarchar(255)=null,
  @LastName nvarchar(255)=null,
  @City nvarchar(255)=null,
  @State nvarchar(255)=null,
  @Country nvarchar(255)=null,
  @PostalCode nvarchar(255)=null,
  @ContactName nvarchar(255)=null,
  @ContactNumber nvarchar(255)=null,
  @Email nvarchar(255)=null,
  @ContactEmail nvarchar(255)=null
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT ClientId FROM [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] WHERE ClientID = @ClientId) 
  --This checks if record is not present for given client id then insert new record
    BEGIN
    --Here in Insert statement pass ClientID only if you dont set ClientID as Primary key with auto-increment
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] 
        (
           ClientId ,FirstName ,LastName,City ,State ,Country ,PostalCode ,ContactName ,ContactNumber ,Email,ContactEmail,InsertedDate)
        VALUES (
           @ClientId ,@FirstName ,@LastName,@City ,@State ,@Country ,@PostalCode ,@ContactName ,@ContactNumber ,@Email,@ContactEmail,getdate()
        )
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  [dbo].[tblClientContactDetails] 
        SET
            FirstName=@FirstName
            ,LastName=@LastName
            ,City=@City 
            ,[State]=@State 
            ,Country=@Country 
            ,PostalCode=@PostalCode 
            ,ContactName=@ContactName 
            ,ContactNumber=@ContactNumber 
            ,Email=@Email
            ,ContactEmail=@ContactEmail
            ,UpdatedDate=getdate()
        WHERE ClientId=@ClientId
    END
END
```

Please let me know, is this works for you ?